# How do you calculate the sum of a scoped variable using Node, Async and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to execute an asynchronous database lookup where each item in an array is looked up and its value added to a sum total.

Right now I have the following code which works as long as the `main` function is located in the same file as the database lookups:

```
// async is the async.js library
// Products is a mongoose Schema
var user = {
  cart: [11, 22, 33],
  orderCost = 0;
}

function getTotal (user, callback) {
  async.each(user.cart, findProduct, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    callback(user);
  });
}

function findProduct (skunumber, callback) {
  Products.findOne({sku: skunumber}, function (err, product) {
    user.orderCost += product.toObject().currentPrice;
    callback();                
  });
}

function main () {
    getTotal(user);
}

main();
```

However, I would like the database functions, in this case `Products.findOne` to be located in a different file.  When this is done, te `findProduct` function will no longer have access to the `user` object which means the `user.orderCost +=` will fail.

Is there an agreed way to avoid this problem? Does the async library have a way to account for this or is there a way in Node directly?

Answer (score 0):

1) you are querying db multiple times to get results you can get in one query like this

```
Products.find({sku: {$in: cart}}, function (err, products) { 
    // use for loop to get total cost here
});
```

2) now change your code to use the above, you can place this function anywhere you want as long as it has access to Products variable

```
function getTotal(cart,callback) {
    Products.find({sku: {$in: cart}, function (err, products) { 
        // get total
        callback (total);
    }); 
}
```

3) use it

```
getTotal(user.cart, function(total){
    console.log(total);
});
```

**Update according to comments**

To only get same number of products from db (since there are multiple products with the same sku) as there's in the cart use code below

```
Products
    .find({sku: {$in: cart}})
    .limit(cart.length)
    .exec( function (err, products) { 
    // use for loop to get total cost here
});
```

Comment: I believe you having a typo (a missing `}` or something) in part two.  Further, for some reason this returns more database objects.  For instance if cart is an array with only two items, I have 5 items being returned from the database. How is that possible?

Comment: OK I see the typo, it's after `{sku: {$in: cart}` <- one more } here. Are you sure you don't have multiple produce with same sku in DB or even without sku?

Comment: Yes, I definitely do have many items with the same `sku`, however, I am passing in an array of 3 identical `skus` and I would like three objects from my database (each of which have those skus) passed back.  So if a user has three things with the sku 5050 in his cart, I would look up and return three things from my db that have the sku 5050

Comment: OK than simply use something like `find(...).limit(cart.length).exec(...)` this only returns number of items equal to number of items in cart.